# How does webpack do code splitting for vendor file in this sample app

Tags: node.js, angularjs, webpack, angular-ui-router, oclazyload

I am new to Webpack. I understand basic concepts of bundeling, code-splitting and chunks, etc.
Now I am trying to sprinkle "Webpack magic" into a legacy angularjs app that uses ui-router. So I downloaded the following sample app from ui-router team:
https://github.com/ui-router/sample-app-angularjs

In the index.html file I see 2 js files references:

```
 <script src="_bundles/vendors~sampleapp.js"></script>
   <script src="_bundles/sampleapp.js"></script>
```

And In the webpack.config.js:

```
 entry: {
     "sampleapp": "./app/bootstrap/bootstrap.js",   }
```

...

```
 optimization: {
     splitChunks: { chunks: 'all', },
   },
```

In the entrypoint bootstrap.js there're the following imports:

```
// Each module registers it states/services/components, with the `ngmodule`
import "../global/global.module";
import "../main/main.module";
import "../contacts/contacts.module";
import "../mymessages/mymessages.module";
import "../prefs/prefs.module";
```

So, all the vendor imports happen in ngmodule.js, but bootstrap.js doesn't import it. And as far I can see it's not referenced in any other modules. Now README does mention something about "oclazyload"

> ocLazyLoad is used to lazy load the angular module

But it's not clear how it happens or where it's configured. So my questions:

1. How does ngmodule.js gets bundled into the vendors.js
2. How does Webpack know that it needs to go into vendor chunk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does Webpack know that it needs to go into vendor chunk?

Well it is directly imported in index.html) Beside this bootstrap.js imports ga.js, ga.js imports ngmodule.js

> How does ngmodule.js gets bundled into the vendors.js

vendors.js is generated with default optimization.splitChunks (https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/)

```
...    
    cacheGroups: {
            vendors: {
              test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
              priority: -10
    }
...
```

so ngmodule.js wont go into vendor itself, but imports from node_modules will.